# Upload Big Dataset (CSV file) into a Database using Python / Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataset

I hope all is well.  I'm working on a data engineering project.  I've been working on this particular problem for a day and half now.  Unfortunately, I'm still spinning my wheels.

I'm presently looking for something that will process a massive dataset with thousands of rows of data, then upload that dataset into a database.  I'm attempting to use the Python Pandas library and upload the data into a data frame for analysis and cleaning.

The "2020 Annual Data" Restaurant Nutrition Datasets can be found here as a free download: https://www.menustat.org/data.html

I've yet to run across a tutorial that shows a successful upload of a massive dataset using a Pandas script, mainly folks demonstrating code with small files with just a few lines of data.

Here's my original Python code:

```
# import libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2

# Read CSV file into a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\rasha\Documents\\rashad\projects\\aws-fast-food\\fast-food-data-2020.csv')

# Shows headers
df.head()
```

I'm running into some interesting errors:

```
1st Code Attempt:  df = pd.read_csv('fast-food-data-2020.csv')
1st Error:  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 20: invalid continuation byte


2nd Code Attempt:  df = pd.read_csv('fast-food-data-2020.csv', encoding='UTF-8')
2nd Error:  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 52676: invalid continuation byte


3rd Code Attempt:  df = pd.read_csv('fast-food-data-2020.csv', encoding='latin-1')
3rd Error:  DtypeWarning: Columns (12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,37,49,52) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  df = pd.read_csv('fast-food-data-2020.csv', encoding='latin-1')


4th Code Attempt:  df = pd.read_csv('fast-food-data-2020.csv', error_bad_lines=False, index_col=False, dtype='unicode')
4th Error:  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 20: invalid continuation byte


5th Code Attempt:  df = pd.read_csv('fast-food-data-2020.csv', low_memory=False)
5th Error:  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 20: invalid continuation byte


6th Code Attempt:  df = pd.read_csv('fast-food-data-2020.csv', engine='python')
6th Code Error:  UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 3524: invalid continuation byte
```

I need to take a break and work on something else.  Hopefully time away will inspire some additional solutions to try out later.  In the meantime, if anyone has any recommendations, any and all feedback is most welcomed.  Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: The link gives back an `.xlsx`. Can you _re-check_ ? **annual_data2020.xlsx**

Comment: I also see an Excel file. After downloading, I could read it using `pd.read_excel`.

Comment: Same here. Downloaded .xlsx, opened with pd.read_excel(filename)

Comment: Ok, I'll check.  I saved the file as .xlsx, but then resaved it as a CSV.

Comment: Excellent, thanks guys.  When attempting to run it using pd.read_excel, I received another error:  

ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.

I entered the following:  pip install openpyxl.

That fixed the problem.  This is great, thanks so much again :-)!